# Nested directives with transclusion gets instantiated multiple times. Why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have following example code which contains three nested directives each depicted as boxes. Each directive has a controller, a pre link function and post link function. As per the angular docs I was expecting an execution order in which first controller and pre link functions execute and in the end all the post link functions will execute in reverse order.

But in the example I can see, it starts to instantiate the controllers again and again as if it were in some sort of recursive loop. This is the order in which things execute.

outer controller executes
outer pre link executes
middle controller executes
middle pre link executes
inner controller executes
inner pre link executes
inner post link executes
inner controller executes
inner pre link executes
inner post link executes
middle post link executes
middle controller executes
middle pre link executes
inner controller executes
inner pre link executes
inner post link executes
inner controller executes
inner pre link executes
inner post link executes
middle post link executes
outer post link executes

*Why would you expect the things to unfold in this order*. Why on earth shall there be more than 9 lines of output.

*Now add to the surprises; If I use angular 1.5.8 the output is exactly 9 lines, as expected. So were all the previous versions of angular buggy or was the documentation !!*

**I need some help in understanding outcome of this code. I am really disturbed with the findings.**

Code is uploaded here:

http://codepen.io/vsjha18-1471636320/details/Grrmwm/

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Training Set</title>

        <!-- styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <!-- JS libs -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div outer class="outer">
            <div middle class="middle">
                <div inner class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <ol>
            <li  ng-repeat="m in message track by $index">{{ m}}</li>
        </ol>

    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.tester = "this means angular is working ...";
    $scope.message = [];
});

app.directive("outer", function(){
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<h1> this is outer</h1> <ng-transclude><ng-transclude>",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.message.push("outer controller executes")
            console.log("outer controller")
        },
        compile: function(elems, attrs, tfn) {
            console.log("outer compile");
            return {
                pre: function(scope, elems, attrs) {
                    scope.message.push("outer pre link executes")
                    console.log("outer pre")
                },
                post: function(scope, elems, attrs) {
                    scope.message.push("outer post link executes")
                    console.log("outer post")
                }
            }
        }
    }
});


app.directive("middle", function(){
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<h1> this is middle </h1><ng-transclude><ng-transclude>",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.message.push("middle controller executes")
            console.log("middle compile")
        },
        compile: function(elems, attrs, tfn) {
            return {
                pre: function(scope, elems, attrs) {
                    scope.message.push("middle pre link executes")
                    console.log("middle pre")
                },
                post: function(scope, elems, attrs) {
                    scope.message.push("middle post link executes")
                    console.log("middle post")
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

app.directive("inner", function(){
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<h1> this is inner </h1>",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.message.push("inner controller executes");
            console.log("inner controller")
        },
        compile: function(elems, attrs, tfn) {
            return {
                pre: function(scope, elems, attrs) {
                    scope.message.push("inner pre link executes");
                    console.log("inner pre")
                },
                post: function(scope, elems, attrs) {
                    scope.message.push("inner post link executes");
                    console.log("inner post")
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

style.css

```
.outer {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
}

.middle {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
}


.inner {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: See [AngularJS Change Logs V1.5.8](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#158-arbitrary-fallbacks-2016-07-22)

Comment: I have gone through the change logs. But I can't understand much from it.